# How to get the exact details of OpenJPA exception for invalid data conversion?

Tags: java, db2, openjpa

I am getting below java exception for a `SELECT` statement via OpenJPA which connect to DB2 database.

Can someone guide me on how to exactly find which column is a mismatch?

The error code `ERRORCODE=-4461` does not really elaborate much.

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: [jcc][t4][1092][11644][3.57.82] Invalid data conversion: Wrong result column type for requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4827) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4787) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary.newStoreException(DB2Dictionary.java:563) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:86) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initialize(JDBCStoreManager.java:347) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.jdbc.kernel.WsJpaJDBCStoreManager.initialize(WsJpaJDBCStoreManager.java:147) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.initialize(DelegatingStoreManager.java:112) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ROPStoreManager.initialize(ROPStoreManager.java:57) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:1005) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:963) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:880) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.find(DelegatingBroker.java:223) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:476) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365) ~[org.springframework.orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy45.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240) ~[org.springframework.orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy45.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411066/errorcode-4461-sqlstate-42815-in-db2) and [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21622381).

I could also see that enabling `<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="db2(SupportsSelectStartIndex=true,SupportsSelectEndIndex=true)"/>` in persistence.xml creates the issue. Commenting that solves it. This is enabled for selecting top 10 rows from result set. The syntax `SELECT TOP 10 FROM SOME_TABLE` does not work with DB2 directly.
But not really sure on why exactly this causes issue.

Comment: Do you think that including the generated SELECT statement, along with the table definition(s), might be useful?

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone guide me on how to exactly find which column is a
>   mismatch?

Can you open class `JDBCStoreManager` in `IDEA` and set breakpoint in first of line of method initialize() when call your `SELECT` statement? I think, you can find out what problem quite easy in debug mode.

Comment: I checked and confirmed that Exception is occurring because of the property in persistence.xml <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="db2(SupportsSelectStartIndex=true,SupportsSelectEndIndex=true)"/>