# How to select top 10 records from DB2 database using OpenJPA?

Tags: java, db2, openjpa

I am trying to select TOP 10 records from DB2 database using OpenJPA. I am trying to get results as specified in query:

```
SELECT * FROM CACHE_REFRESH_TABLE FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

For that I have enabled below property in my `persistence.xml`.

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="db2(SupportsSelectStartIndex=true,SupportsSelectEndIndex=true)"/>
```

But after enabling the property it throws an exception for other simple SELECT queries as I had mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270152/how-to-get-the-exact-details-of-openjpa-exception-for-invalid-data-conversion).

The Java code I am using to retrieve the TOP 10 records is as follows. But it does not work as it forms the SELECT as `SELECT TOP 10 FROM CACHE_REFRESH_TABLE` and not as

```
SELECT * FROM CACHE_REFRESH_TABLE FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Below is the Java code.

```
public List<CacheHistoryOTO> fetchRefreshHistory(
                int someInput1, String someInput2) throws SomeException {
            LOGGER.info(EventMessages.METH_START, "fetchRefreshHistory");
            List<CacheHistoryOTO> cacheHistoryOTOList = null;
            try {
                EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerProvider
                        .getEntityManager();
                final Query query = entityManager
                        .createNamedQuery("topHistoryRecords");
                query.setMaxResults(someInput1);//Depending on parameter someInput1 number of records to be fetched will be provided.

                cacheHistoryOTOList = (List<CacheHistoryOTO>) query
                        .getResultList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(EventMessages.ERROR, e);
                throw new SomeException(Constant.ERROR_PERSISTENCE, e);
            }
            LOGGER.info(EventMessages.METH_END, "fetchRefreshHistory");
            return cacheHistoryOTOList;
    }
```

Named query is declared as follows.

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "topHistoryRecords", query = "SELECT cacheRefreshHistoryOTO FROM CacheHistoryOTO cacheRefreshHistoryOTO ORDER BY cacheRefreshHistoryOTO.refreshTimeStamp DESC")
        })
```

Can someone please suggest to use the right way to do this?

I have looked at [JPA 2 CriteriaQuery, using a limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655870/jpa-2-criteriaquery-using-a-limit) but did not help.

Comment: seems like a dialect issue to me. `TOP 10` is something i'd expect to see in SQL-Server. Can you share the datasource setup?